# Allow copy/paste on editing questions/answer

Tags: feature-request

*Not 100% this is the right place to ask about this.*

It happens pretty often that I'm reading what I'm writing in an SO question/answer from the preview box, and that I want to copy/paste some content (eg. two examples of code, I want to duplicate the first one).

But it feels like SO has a `$('#previw').on('change', renderInMarkdown);`-isch code somewhere, which cancels selection because it is deleted and recreated immediately.

I recently faced the issue on one of my websites, and solved it accordingly:

```
$('#previw').on('change', function(){
  var currentContent = $(this).html();
  var newContent = $(this).renderInMarkdown();
  if (currentContent != newContent) {
    $(this).html(newContent);
  }
});
```

It works perfectly for me and I think it would be a great benefit for many SO users.

Comment: I would suggest adding a series of steps that reproduce the undesirable behavior. There's a greater chance that the devs are going to want to look into it if you include this.

Comment: When you try to select from the *preview* of a post you're writing editing, that selection is lost when you release e.g. release the mouse button, and focus is pulled back to the input box. You can get around this by hitting Ctrl-C *before* releasing the mouse button.

Comment: Yes, I meant from the preview box. :) Thanks for the workaround, but I can't see any reason why we'd have to support this behavior ...

Comment: If this is a bug-report, that just gets a [meta-tag:status-bydesign]. If you hange it to a [meta-tag:feature-request], that's a [tag:duplicate-questions].

Comment: Ok, we can consider this is a feature-request (though I'd call it a UX issue). To which question is it a duplicate?